# What is this 'stuff' in the command being sent to screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

To send Control+C to a detached screen-session I can do as [has been](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2012-05/msg00007.html) [demonstrated elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006504/541058):

```
screen -S NameOfSession -p 0 -X stuff $'\003
```

or

```
screen -S NameOfSession -X -p 0 stuff "^C"
```

My question is about 'stuff' in the command. The man pages for screen doesn't mention it, and it doesn't appear to be an application installed in my Linux dist either.

Could someone please elaborate about what 'stuff' actually is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as I were about to post, I realized that the switch `-X` doesn't take any arbitrary command, it actually has a list of specific commands it accepts, [reference here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Paste).

So, to quote the reference:

> Stuff the string string in the input buffer of the current window. This is like the paste command, but with much less overhead. You cannot paste large buffers with the stuff command. It is most useful for key bindings.